# SWIG/Python: Unable to access referenced parameter in Python callback

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, callback, swig

In SWIG, I've got a wrapped C++ base class that is inherited in Python. The C++ side invokes callbacks on the Python derived class, which works fine. Unfortunately, one of the parameters of the callback is passed as reference. Accessing this reference yields:

> Fatal unhandled exception: SWIG director method error. Error detected
> when calling 'Base.Start'

```
test.i

%module(directors="1", allprotected="1") test
%feature("director") Base;

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual bool Start(const Property& config) = 0; // PASSED AS REFERENCE

};

enum PropertyType{PT_REAL, PT_STRING};
class Property
{
    public:
        PropertyType GetType() const;
        int GetSize() const;
};
```

In Python, `Start` is correctly callback/invoked. Unfortunately, invoking `GetType()` or `GetSize()` yields the error above. Invoking functions of parameters passed as pointer is going fine.

```
import test

class PyClient(test.Base):
    def Start(self, config):
        config_size = config.GetSize() // YIELDS ERROR
        config_type = config.GetType() // YIELDS ERROR
        return True
```

I guess I need to convert the parameter Property from a reference to a pointer, but it is unclear to me how this works in SWIG.

UPDATE

It seems the argument in the invoked callback has a different underlying type than when created on the `Python` side.

```
def Start(self, config):
    prop_test = test.Property()
    type_test = prop_test.GetType() #FINE

    type_test2 = config.GetType() # ERROR
```

When a `Property` (`prop_test`) is created on the `Python` side in `Start()`, its type is

```
<mds.Property; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Property *' at 0x000001CC24DA3D80> >
```

Whereas the passed property has a type

```
<Swig Object of type 'Base::Property *' at 0x000001CC24CBE1E0>
```

I wonder whether this is expected, or this might lead to the underlying issue.

Swig 4.0.2

Any help would be really appreciated.

Ben

Comment: Make an [mcve].  This won't build to reproduce and my guess at filling in the blanks worked for me.  You don't need any special handling, and I just did the minimum from your partial code to make it compile and run.

Comment: Yes, per your update, without the proxy wrapper it won't work correctly.  It is an opaque pointer to Python.  In my example, whether created by Python or the C++ code, there is a proxy wrapper, so how are you passing the `PyClient` instance into C++ from Python?  You haven't shown that.  *Again* make a [mcve].

Comment: Aslo, what version of SWIG are you using?  I'm using 4.0.2 (the latest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I finally figured it out, turned out that the `Property` class was in a different namespace in the `C++` code, but not in the SWIG interface file.

By setting the right namespace, a proxy was generated and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You've not provided a reproducible example, so I just filled in the blanks of missing code and it worked.  Here's my working example if it helps:

test.i:

```cpp
%module(directors="1", allprotected="1") test

%feature("director") Base;

%inline %{
enum PropertyType{PT_REAL, PT_STRING};
class Property
{
    PropertyType m_prop;
    int m_size;
public:
    Property(PropertyType prop, int size) : m_prop(prop), m_size(size) {}
    PropertyType GetType() const { return m_prop; }
    int GetSize() const { return m_size; }
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual bool Start(const Property& config) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

void demo(Base* obj) {
    Property prop(PT_STRING,2);
    obj->Start(prop);
}
%}
```

ex.py:

```py
import test

class PyClient(test.Base):
    def Start(self, config):
        config_size = config.GetSize()
        config_type = config.GetType()
        print(f'{config_size=} {config_type=}')
        return True

p = PyClient()
test.demo(p)
```

Output:

```
config_size=2 config_type=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know this works. However, in my code, Start() is a callback, invoked from the C++ side, not from the Python side...

Comment: @Ben Edited above to add a C++ function that takes a `Base*` and calls its `Start` method.  It still works.  If you still have an issue, edit your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks again. The problem is that the Start function is being invoked from a Nuget package, which makes it hard to create a self-containing example, I did find something interesting, which has been added to the question.

Comment: @Ben Where it is invoked shouldn’t matter, so replace the Nuget piece with another C++ call and see if it produces the same error. *Try* to make a [mcve].  Maybe you have something wrong in your .i file or build process

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but setting up an example, I found the issue (see below)

Comment: @Ben And *that’s* why you make MREs, most of the time you figure it out without resorting to SO.